# Can you change a Greyhound ticket so that only the last leg is a day later?

Tags: buses, greyhound

I'm traveling from Portland, OR to Navasota, TX with stops in Denver and Fort Worth. In Fort Worth, I want to rest and get an Airbnb and take the bus the day later to Navasota instead of directly transferring in Fort Worth between two buses on the same day like my original itinerary planned. Is it possible for me to go to a Greyhound ticket counter, pay the $20 fee, and change my itinerary so that only the last bus is changed to a day later but the earlier two bus tickets remain the same?

Comment: Several years ago I was able to travel on Greyhound with a ticket dated before the actual schedule I got on, as I had missed the bus. They didn't bother to change it at the ticket counter; they just said to get on the next bus with the ticket I had. I don't know if this is still possible, so I'm not going to commit to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Greyhound](https://www.greyhound.com/en/help-and-info/contact-us) is generally flexible, and allows for exchanges.

> **What you can change**
>
> You can swap your ticket for a new date and time, but you won't be able to change where you're traveling from or to. Before you contact us, check the rules on [ticket exchanges](https://www.greyhound.com/help-and-info/travel-dilemmas/ticket-refunds-exchanges/):
>
> **How to exchange tickets**
>
> You can exchange your ticket at any [Greyhound station](http://locations.greyhound.com/), before the travel departure date on your ticket.
>
> **Contact**
>
> Call from U.S. toll-free 1-800-231-2222 Open 24/7
>   Call from outside the U.S. 214-849-8100 Open 24/7
>   Email: ifsr@greyhound.com